# Install of laravel 4 from pagodabox breaks on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get laravel to work on local host from pagodabox? I've installed laravel 4 through pagoda box, then cloned it to localhost. I then ran composer install to get all the dependencies and updates. When I try to navigate the URI to the public directory, it doesn't show me a "you have arrived" screen. Instead I get the following error message:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [tcp://tunnel.pagodabox.com:6379]

I then looked in "database.php" and noticed that the `redis` array was modified, so I copied the same one from a fresh installation of Laravel, but then I got the following error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Comment: After digging through the github repo issues I found the solution: https://github.com/briankiewel/pagodabox-laravel-4/issues/9
Since the author of the repo switched to redis "database.php", "cache.php" and "session.php" need to be configured back to default values. One can compare the default installation of those three files to configure it back to normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Had the same problem, just change the **bootstrap > start.php** file, search for

`'local' => array('your-machine-name')`

and change it with your machine name.

This video help me to deal with that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJoU-LO8Ufo , in the video he changes it to the virtual host but that didn't work for me, i had to put my computer name.

On Mac the computer name can be found by typing `hostname` in the terminal.

Comment: Same issue, for windows users to get your machine name: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/knowing-hostnames-and-renaming-windows-8-computer

Answer (score 1):

Joshdcid's answer is right for some, but not all. I found this in my bootstrap > start.php file:

```
'local' => array('homestead')
```

..., and changing that variable in any way caused my laravel app to not load at all. Not only that, but in a fresh install of laravel, this local variable had the same value of 'homestead'.

After spending a bit of time in WinMerge, I found that you should use Wayne's tip of changing

```
'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => 'tunnel.pagodabox.com',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

to

```
'redis' => array(

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => array(
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ),

),
```

at the bottom of the app > config > database.php file, then you should also go to the top of the
app > config > session.php file and change

```
'driver' => 'redis',
```

to

```
'driver' => 'file',
```

..., just as a fresh install would have. You should be able to view your app now!